# GA Enhanced Ecommerce: using string value for the Step field instead of a numeric value

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, universal-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

With Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce, can I use a *string value* for the `step` field, in measuring [checkout process](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#measuring-checkout), instead of using a numeric (integer) value?

Something like this:

```
ga('ec:setAction','checkout', {
  // Instead of: 'step': 1,
  'step': 'login',
});

//

ga('ec:setAction','checkout', {
  // Instead of: 'step': 2,
  'step': 'shipping_method',
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't use a string value. The step must be an integer; however, if you are wanting to label your step names in your checkout funnel so that in your reports, like Checkout Behavior, you see steps like 'billing', or 'payment', or 'shipping address', then you can assign names to your steps in the GA enhanced e-commerce configuration page. Read step 7 here, https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6032539?hl=en.